# OSPF: PT(M)P vs NBMA

Tags: ospf

I understand the differences between PT(M)P and NBMA:

- PT(M)P uses dynamic neighbor discovery and multicast, while NBMA does not
- NBMA elects a DR, while PT(M)P does not

I'm trying to optimize a network composed almost exclusively with wireless links. What, if any, advantages does PT(M)P have over NBMA other than dynamic neighbor discovery? And conversely, what advantages, if any, does NBMA have over PT(M)P other than not using multicast?

Comment: When configuring OSPF, you really need to look at the link protocols. Is the link a broadcast link, e.g. ethernet or Wi-Fi with multiple routers on the link? If so, you should use broadcast. If you are running a WAN link, the NBMA or PTMP may be more appropriate, and if the link is a PTP link, then P2P is probably more appropriate. You really need to give us more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the practical differences are, as you point out, whether OSPF speakers on a given multi-access network will dynamically form adjacencies or if explicit neighbor relationships need to be configured.

It used to be that the decision of which method was dictated by both the transport in use and the feature sets supported on the software / hardware platform.  The classic case was frame-relay / X.25 where, initially, a manual mapping of unicast IP to hardware destination has to be maintained.  The lack of any notion of broadcast (let alone multicast!) meant that adjacencies also had to be manually set up.  This approach was augmented with the use of per-destination subinterfaces, which moved to the classic point-to-point L3 configuration and attendant automatic adjacency formation.  It's also worth noting that other IGP's (notably IS-IS) didn't support NBMA at all.

More recently it's rare to find a physical transport that requires the use of NBMA, but certain logical transports (ex: certain NHRP-based VPN's) can still require it under certain circumstances.

So - assuming the transport can support either p-t-p or NBMA topologies the pros and cons are basically this:

NBMA - more efficient IP utilization, likely somewhat less overall router configuration.

Point-to-Point - A logical interface per connection burns more IP's and potentially requires lots of configuration.  It also allows for the granular deployment of features like QoS and security and arguably provides a much cleaner mechanism of troubleshooting, capacity analysis and traffic engineering.

Ultimately the two approaches don't vary in terms of the number of adjacencies (and associated overhead).  There's going to be some advantage to the NBMA approach in terms of numbers of LSA's generated (one per subnet for one /24 vs 128 /31's) but the actual impact of this is going to vary tremendously with network design and hardware capacity.

To sum it up - if both options are available and scale isn't an issue then I would tend toward the operational benefits of point-to-point.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the information. The main problem with non-NBMA modes for me is my network is almost exclusively made of wireless links, so from what I've seen it seems it would perform better with unicast rather than multicast. Is this a bad assumption?

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson  I don't see any reason for unicast performing better than multicast. If you have large volumes of traffic (not at all the case for IGP control messages) you will gain better performance from multicast as opposed to unicast. For IGP it doesn't really matter. Focus on timers, topology and traffic pattern instead.

Comment: @artem_d93 Here is my source: https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Multicast_detailed_example#Multicast_and_Wireless

Comment: For the reasons I mentioned above I would stick with unicast/p-t-p in a wireless network.  The more you can deconstruct the network into a series of deterministic links the better you'll be able to manage issues on individual spans.  It's not that NBMA wouldn't work but that the wireless use-case would make failures a lot trickier to definitively track.

Comment: @rnxrx You seem to contradict yourself. You say use unicast, but then say don't use NBMA, the only network type to use unicast.

Comment: Sorry - I meant a series of point-to-point networks versus a multi-access segment, whether that segment inherently supports broadcast or not.  Put another way - each span becomes a /31 rather than all the spans shared in a /24 with either a series of network statements (NBMA) or a standard shared segment with DR/BDR.